# How to code and wrap with ctypes a python function needed as callback by sqlite3?

Tags: python, c, sqlite, callback, ctypes

I'm trying to perform `sqlite3_exec` from python to extract line by line the contents of a database. According to the [C API](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html), I need a Callback function which will perform the iteration. I have coded the following with a lot of help from internet:

**UPDATED with @eryksun pièces of advice**

```
import ctypes

def extractor(unused, num_columns, pcolumn, pcolumn_name):
    for column in range(0,num_columns):
        if pcolumn[i] != None:
            print pcolumn[i]

sqlite3DLL = ctypes.CDLL("C:\\Python\\PYTHON\\DLLs\\sqlite3.dll")
SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY = 1 
null_ptr = ctypes.c_void_p(None)
p_src_db = ctypes.c_void_p(None)

ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))
callback_func = callback_type(extractor)

connect = sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_open_v2(DatabasePath, ctypes.byref(p_src_db), SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, null_ptr)
connect = sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_exec(DatabasePath, "SELECT * FROM *", callback_func, None, null_ptr)
sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_close(DatabasePath)
```

Before moving on to the python callback function I have some doubts:

1. Is `"SELECT * FROM *"` a possible **SQL statement** to avoid providing the name of a table (because I do not know it)?
2. Is the first argument of both functions `sqlite3_open_v2` and `sqlite3_exec` the path to the database?

If all that is ok we can move on to the callback function. According to what I found on the net, the C callback function should be somewhat similar to:

```
callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL")}
```

That is why I coded the `CFUNCTYPE` you see on my code. How can I code a python function which matches the callback needed to maybe fill a list with the database contents?

I have added the proposed changes on the code, the callback function just prints the value to verify the output. But It wont work I get an error:

```
con = sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_exec(FastenerLibraryPath, "SELECT * FROM *", callback_func, None, null_ptr)
WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000009
```

Many thanks in advance!

**FINAL WORKING EDITION (@eryksun comments and @MarkTolonen solution)**

```
import ctypes

def extractor(unused, num_columns, pcolumn, pcolumn_name):
    print ','.join(["''" if x is None else "'"+x+"'" for x in pcolumn[:num_columns]])
    return 0

sqlite3DLL = ctypes.CDLL("C:\\Python\\PYTHON\\DLLs\\sqlite3.dll")
SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY = 1 
null_ptr = ctypes.c_void_p(None)
p_src_db = ctypes.c_void_p(None)

ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))
callback_func = callback_type(extractor)

connect = sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_open_v2(DatabasePath, ctypes.byref(p_src_db), SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, None)
connect = sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_exec(p_src_db, b"SELECT * FROM Pin", callback_func, None, None)
sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_close(p_src_db)
```

This is working, however, I will look into `argtypes` and the opaque type.

Thank you all!

Comment: The `sqlite3_exec()` callback is hard to use even in C. Better use a [cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5456/sqlite3-stmt-prepared-statement-c-api/).

Comment: The callback type should be `ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))`. You can use it as a decorator for a Python function with the signature `(unused, num_columns, pcolumn, pcolumn_name)`. Iterate over `range(num_columns)`. If the ith column is empty, then `pcolumn[i]` should be `None`, so the equivalent of the C ternary is `pcolumn[i] if pcolumn[i] else b'NULL'`. For success, return 0. If the callback returns a non-zero value, `sqlite3_exec` returns `SQLITE_ABORT`.

Comment: Or just use the Python-included [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) library?

Comment: @MarkTolonen, Chang is using sqlite3.dll from Python's installation directory and hopefully knows about the sqlite3 module. I assumed this was needed for something not implemented by the module or for educational purposes.

Comment: Using `WinDLL` (stdcall) is wrong with sqlite3.dll. It should be `CDLL` (cdecl). You'll only see a problem in 32-bit Python. The cdecl and stdcall calling conventions are ignored in x64.

Comment: Thanks @CL. I will take a look this evening to your link.

Comment: Yes, @MarkTolonen I know the `sqlite3` Library. This is for educational purposes like  @eryksun said. I cannot install any libraries because of my network administrator. But I am working on this workaround with the `.dll`

Comment: Thank you @eryksun, I have tried everything you suggested, but I get an error. I have updated my post to include your proposals and the error.

Comment: `sqlite3_exec` and `sqlite3_close` take the handle for the db connection, `p_src_db`, not the database path. Also, the callback has to return an integer value. Return 0 for success.

Comment: You should really start with defining an opaque type for the database connection handle instead of using a generic `c_void_p`. Define an empty struct as follows: `class sqlite3(ctypes.Structure): pass`. Then create a pointer type for it: `psqlite3 = ctypes.POINTER(sqlite3)`. Then define `argtypes` for the functions you're using, so you'll get a better exception (or avoid segfaulting in Unix) if the wrong type is passed for an argument.

Comment: I don't think `SELECT * FROM *` works. If you don't know a table name, you can use a sqlite3 browser program to inspect the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 (if you change the DLL path) using the following database:

```
create table tbl1(one varchar(10), two smallint);
insert into tbl1 values('hello',10);
insert into tbl1 values('goodbye',20);
```

Code:

```
# I know, bad form, but it makes the code easier to read for an example
from ctypes import *

# This was missing the 2nd c_int parameter.
CALLBACK = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_void_p, c_int, POINTER(c_char_p), POINTER(c_char_p))

@CALLBACK
def extractor(unused, num_columns, pcolumn, pcolumn_name):
    print(pcolumn[:num_columns])
    return 0 # needs to return 0 from callback or will abort.

sqlite3DLL = CDLL(r"C:\Python27\DLLs\sqlite3.dll")
SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY = 1 
p_src_db = c_void_p()

sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_open_v2(b'test.db', byref(p_src_db), SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY, None)
# pass the handle returned by above as first parameter below
sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_exec(p_src_db, b'SELECT * FROM tbl1', extractor, None, None)
sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_close(p_src_db)
```

Output:

```
['hello', '10']
['goodbye', '20']
```

I also recommend setting `argtypes` because it helps catch type errors and for some parameter types (like c_double) it is required.

```
sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_open_v2.argtypes = c_char_p, POINTER(c_void_p), c_int,c_char_p
sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_open_v2.restype = c_int

sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_exec.argtypes = c_void_p,c_char_p,CALLBACK,c_void_p,POINTER(c_char_p)
sqlite3DLL.sqlite3_open_v2.restype = c_int
```

Comment: You'll gain more type safety if you define an opaque `sqlite3` type and a `psqlite3` pointer type to use in `argtypes`. Using `c_void_p` for the connection handle is very permissive -- not that some APIs don't do this (e.g. Windows).